# JDK 11+ and Javadoc

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, java-11, maven-javadoc-plugin

```
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - The code being documented uses packages in the unnamed module, but the packages defined in https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/ are in named modules.
```

Has anyone been able to make javadoc work without having to change the source version to 1.8 (as suggested in other forums)? I'm using JDK v11.0.5 and the issue still present (also with JDK 12+).

Edit: This error originated from maven and thrown by the maven-javadoc-plugin. I have not been able to make it work for JDK 11+ even with the `<source>8</source>` configuration.

Comment: Related https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8212233

Comment: I think this question needs some more details. Do you use maven? Do you use or have you tried to use modules in your project?

Comment: @rü- you're right, I have updated the post, thanks. Yes, I am using maven with a multi-module setup.

Comment: With the latest javadoc plugin it is working for me. I originally had source set to 8 and it was failing. Given your observation I'm guessing this was fixed in a later version I'm using 3.2.0 currently

Answer (score 53):

As [suggested in OpenJDK issue tracker](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8212233) this can be worked around with defining source on Javadoc plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>8</source>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Probably, you didn't read the question completely. OP has clearly mentioned: `Has anyone been able to make javadoc work without having to change the source version to 1.8`

Comment: it works for me. I use: <configuration>
                            <source>${java.version}</source>
                        </configuration> and in properties it's java 11. I just had to specify the version for some reason.

Comment: How can you do this in Gradle?

Comment: When using JDK 8, I set it to 1.8, not 8. Perhaps both work.

Comment: Also suggested as the solution in https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8212233

Comment: I used version 11 on my build, and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 31):

Adding `<detectJavaApiLink>false</detectJavaApiLink>` to the Maven javadoc pluging configuration fix the error

Comment: This worked for me using AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.8 (2020-07-14) on a Mac. I already had `<source>8</source>` set and it was working for other versions of JDK 11, but not for 11.0.8.

Answer (score 24):

I needed the bit from Carlos Santos to make this really work. The complete config that incorporates his answer is:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>8</source>
    <detectJavaApiLink>false</detectJavaApiLink>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks. Even without `<source>8</source>`, the above snippet still works for me, in combination with `<properties>maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source><maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target></properties>`

Answer (score 6):

[javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javadoc.html) produces links to packages you use, e.g. to classes documented in `.../javase/11/docs/api`. While your comments are in an unnamed module, the targets are not, and javadoc can't combine those two. It produces either a `package-list` or an `element-list` file, so you can't mix unnamed modules (packages) with named modules.

I didn't find a way to limit the links that javadoc tries to produce; so you may have to use modules for your own project. This seems ridiculous to me, just to make javadoc happy. I guess this is just one of the reasons that so many people stick to Java 8.

Comment: I fully agree. Further it would be helpful if maven-javadoc-plugin would tell which modules are unnamed so you can trace down the problem in a very large project. Also it could offer an option to ignore unnamend modules in aggregation. This does not seem to be the case: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/aggregate-mojo.html

Comment: @Jörg Yes, this is all super-annoying isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get my own project to work by using a new version of the compiler plugin and setting the release property to 8.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</plugin>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>
</properties>
```

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same issue. I was using **Java 11.0.3** and **org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.4:jar**. Updating the maven-javadoc-plugin version to **3.2.0** worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I am using maven-javadoc-plugin version 3.2.0 and get exactly this error. So that does not fix the issue.

Comment: @Jörg Which Java version are you using?

Comment: My Java version is 11.0.5+10

Answer (score -3):

We can use `<detectOfflineLinks>false</detectOfflineLinks>` in the configuration.