# maven-javadoc-plugin fails on jdk 11 when compiling for jdk 8

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin, openjdk-11

I have a maven-wise simple project targeting Java 1.8 [here](https://github.com/t1/stereotype-helper).

`mvn javadoc:javadoc` runs fine on OpenJDK 8, but fails on OpenJDK 11 with this error message:

```
javadoc: error - The code being documented uses modules but the packages defined in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ are in the unnamed module.
```

WTF?!? I'm not doing anything with modules!

I couldn't find anything helpful on the web, even though I'd assume this to be a quite common problem. Maybe it's just because most people still stick to Java 8.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate. [They](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836862/jdk-11-and-javadoc) have `Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - The code being documented uses packages in the unnamed module, but the packages defined in https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/ are in named modules.`
I have `javadoc: error - The code being documented uses modules but the packages defined in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ are in the unnamed module.`

And I _can_ change the source version; I only have to do this also for the `maven-javadoc-plugin`.

I feel bossed a little.

Comment: @user7294900: I'd like to answer my own question now, as I found out how to work around. The [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836862/jdk-11-and-javadoc) doesn't have the same solution, even though it seems to have the same cause. Could you remove the Duplicate, please?

Comment: Hi, have same problem was your solution ?